# Selenium by JAVA, trying to click Login button

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="sign-up-btn">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
</div>
```

To click Login, what should I do?

```
driver.findElement(By........("submit")).click();
```

How can I get to use type for it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this...

1. A CSS selector like

   ```
   div.sign-up-btn > button
   ```
2. An XPath like

   ```
   //button[text()='Log in']
   ```
3. Use the type attribute using a CSS selector, as you requested, but it's possible that this locator isn't unique on the page

   ```
   button[type='submit']
   ```

You may need to add a wait to ensure that the button is clickable, e.g.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.sign-up-btn > button"))).click();
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.button[type='submit]).click(); It didn't work when I did it.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\ujjwa\\Desktop\\Project\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); // Opens up Chrome Browser

  driver.get("https://moodle.ulm.edu/"); // Opens up ULM website

  driver.manage().window().maximize(); // Maximize the window opened

  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("parajuu");

  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Abc123xyz123");

  driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.button[type='submit]).click();

  // driver.quit();

Comment: `By.button` is not a valid locator type. You need to use the code that I posted in my answer.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.div(sign-up-btn>button).click();    Do you mean like this? But it did not worked either

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.sign-up-btn > button")).click();  I did like this and it finally worked. Thank you. Cheers

Comment: I'm assuming you are using an IDE like Eclipse? The code you are posting won't build. You have changed `By.button` to `By.div` but that's not a locator type either. The locator to use is in my answer. You should probably spend some time reading [the Selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/locating_elements/) also since you seem to be struggling with the basics.

Comment: If this answer or any answer helped you, please upvote it. Once you find the answer that works for you, please mark it as accepted so that others don't waste time trying to answer it.